# website is freezing while downloading big file in php

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I'm downloading big `.mp4` file with php. I'm using download button to download, but when i click the download button, website is freezing and i can not move anywhere else. I searched on the internet i tried almost everything to avoid this situation but i couldn't. i couldn't find the solution. Hope you can help me. thanks in advance.

**Here is the download code** :

```
  function download($file){

$ext = explode(".", $file);
switch($ext[sizeof($ext)-1])
{
  case "mp4": $mime = "video/mp4"; break;
  case "m4a": $mime = "audio/mp4"; break;
  case "m4p": $mime = "audio/mp4"; break;
 }

header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

    $ch = curl_init($file);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

 curl_close($ch);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Length: '. $size);
ob_clean();
ob_end_clean() ;

readfile($file);
 exit();

}


if(isset($_POST['indir'])) { 
$file=...
download($file);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that a download triggered on the server freezes your browser? Or web server and browser are on the same PC?

Comment: @ntd Web server and browser on the same pc. I tried in my localhost. I'm searching the solution for 8 hours still i couldn't find.

Comment: well, at least I'd try another browser to see if the problem is on the client or on the server side. I'd also try (if possible) to send the same request directly from command line with curl.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `readfile()` can cause issues while processing large files (even though the PHP documentation says otherwise)

You can try reading it in chunks:

```
$fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")
while(!feof($fd)) {
    $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
    echo $buffer;
}
fclose ($fd);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried but it doesn't work. still the same

Comment: @user3583237 ok, in that case you need to pinpoint where it starts hanging in the first place. I suggest you debug by commenting out the lines and incrementally uncommenting, while checking if the site loses responsiveness.

Comment: I did what you suggested I think it is about the `readfile()` process.

Comment: and it is also when you use `fread()` instead of `readfile()`?

Comment: unfortunately yes it is also when i use `fread()` instead of `readfile()`. I really need to solve this problem today but i cant..